# UDP recvfrom not working

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp

I have UDP Server program which receives data from port 7888. The server code is below.

```
//UDPIPV4Server.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;

class UDPIPV4Server
{
public:
    UDPIPV4Server();
    ~UDPIPV4Server(void);
    UINT type;
    string mac_address;
    UINT port;
    int socket_var;
    struct sockaddr_in si_server, si_client;


    int Config(void);
    int RecvData(char* recv_buffer, int buf_size,string *ip_addr);
};

//UDPIPV4Server.cpp
int UDPIPV4Server::Config(void) {
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int error = WSAStartup(0X0202, &wsadata);

    if(error) {
        cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp:- WSAStartup failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if ((socket_var = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp:- socket function failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    memset((char *) &si_server, 0, sizeof(si_server));
    si_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_server.sin_port = htons(7888);
    char host[NI_MAXHOST] = "10.8.0.2";
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, host, &si_server.sin_addr) != 1) {
        cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp: inet_pton() failed\n";
        return -1;
    }
    if(bind(socket_var,(struct sockaddr *)&si_server,sizeof(si_server)) == -1) {
            cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp:- bind failed: "<<endl;
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//recv data from the UDP client
//recv_buffer - [out] receive buffer
//buf_size - [in] size of receive buffer in bytes
//ip_addr - [out] ip address of the remote client
int UDPIPV4Server::RecvData(char* recv_buffer, int buf_size, string *ip_addr) {
    int recv_len;
    cout<<"waiting for data\n";
    memset((char*)&si_client, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    int si_client_len = sizeof(si_client);
    if((recv_len = recvfrom(socket_var, recv_buffer, buf_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_client, &si_client_len)) == -1) {
        cerr<<"udpipv4server.cpp:- recvfrom failed"<<endl;
        return recv_len;
    }
    char client_addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    cout<<"Received packets from "<<inet_ntoa(si_client.sin_addr)<<":"<<ntohs(si_client.sin_port)<<endl;
    *ip_addr = inet_ntoa(si_client.sin_addr);
    return recv_len;
}
//main.cpp
#include "UDPIPV4Server.h"
int main() {
UDPIPV4Server udp_server;
udp_server.Config();
char recv_frame_buffer[65534] = "";
memset(recv_frame_buffer,0,sizeof(recv_frame_buffer));
int retval;
string ip_addr;
if((retval = udp_server.RecvData(recv_frame_buffer,sizeof(recv_frame_buffer),&ip_addr)) ==  -1) {
    cerr<<"ReceiverCommModule:- Error in receving data"<<endl;
    continue;
}
}
```

The above program receives data on 10.8.0.2:7888. But this code is not working when data is received. I have checked with wireshark, the data is being received at 10.8.0.2:7888. But socket is unable to read the data from the port.The `UDPIPV4Server.config()` function passed successfully. But the `UDPIPV4Server.RecvData()` is not returning. The UDP `recvfrom` is waiting as such there is no data received. Is it anything wrong with the code? Thank you.

Comment: If you're writing OS-specific code, it's good to include the related tag (Windows).  If UDPIPV4Server is part of a 3rd party library you should name it and provide a link; if it's all your code you should extract/include enough of the library to create a minimal example program that reproduces the problem.  *"But socket is unable to read the data from the port."* - that's too vague: is `recvfrom` not returning, or returning such that "recvfrom failed" gets printed?

Comment: "socket is unable to read the data" is not a problem description. Try again. NB Don't print `"bind failed", "recvfrom failed",` etc. Print the actual error, as `errno,` or with `strerror()`, or `perror().` Same for all system calls, not just `bind().` Otherwise debugging is just a guessing game.

Comment: @TonyD i have edited the code. The issues is `UDP recvfrom` wait as if no data is received. But in wireshark i can clearly see data being received.

Comment: I haven't noticed any obvious bug.  You could change from `inet_pton` to `.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);` temporarily - which means it will be monitoring all intefaces - see if that's relevant.

Comment: Make sure your firewall will allow packets on that port - wireshark usually monitors before the firewall.

Comment: @kbickar i created a rule on inbound connections settings, to allow packets on that particular port. Is it enough?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. in UDP, recvfrom behaves as if no data were available dispite wireshark confirmed that a valid UDP packet arrived on the correct port. It happens on my compagny's computer but it works fine on my personnal one. I guess this is linked to windows fire wall or antivir that filters incoming packets if the associated port is not allowed for your software. I noticed that recvfrom works once, just after having sent packet through the same port. May be this is linked to my computer's config.